# XMLHttpRequest that is being Aborted

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking over a bit of code that deals with XHR. It looks like the first XHR.send() is being done successfully and then the subsequent one is Aborted before it gets to it's .send()

Quick in dirty:

```
url = "http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/test.cgi";
data = "1235,123,21,1232,12321,432";
myXHR = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  myXHR[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myXHR[i].open("POST", url, true);

  myXHR[i].onerror = function() {
   alert("Error occurred");
  };

  myXHR[i].onload = function() {
    if(myXHR[i].status == 200) {
      alert("Yay I worked");
      var data = myXHR[i].responseText;
    }
   };

   // do some setting up of XHR headers

   myXHR[i].send(data);

   myXHR[i] = null;
}
```

What could be happening that would cause Firebug to show Abort before the second .send() is done?

Comment: Can you remove `myXHR[i] = null;` and tell us what happens? Also, does the url send CORS headers?

Comment: Still happens if I remove the assigning null.
CORS being Cross-Server? The request is actually sent to itself so there is no crossing of subnets or domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was happening.

The XHR was being aborted because there was no return value from the webserver that the request was being sent to. The web server is a custom based one that we seem to be using the someone changed the code so that it wasn't sending a 200 Success OK even if the data sent to it had no data coming back.

All good now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
url = "http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/test.cgi";
data = "1235,123,21,1232,12321,432";
var myXHR = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  myXHR[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myXHR[i].open("POST", url, true);

  myXHR[i].onerror = function() {
   alert("Error occurred");
  };

  myXHR[i].onload = function() {
    if(myXHR[i].status == 200) {
      alert("Yay I worked");
      var data = myXHR[i].responseText;
    }
   };

   // do some setting up of XHR headers

   myXHR[i].send(data);

   myXHR[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to mention the adjustments made to the code so people don't have to visually compare it to OP's example. "Try this" isn't really helpful

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code I get `TypeError: myXHR[i] is undefined` (on the stock firefox 20 install on my mac... what version are you on)?

At any rate, I can see one issue with this (i.e. myXHR[i] will be undefined...) that might also apply to you, in particular with:

```
myXHR[i].onload = function() {
  if(myXHR[i].status == 200) {
    alert("Yay I worked");
    var data = myXHR[i].responseText;
  }
};
```

Because this is triggered asynchronously `i` will have been incremented to 2, which is of course going to be outside the bounds of the two element `myXHR` array. Have you tried closing over the value of `i`, like so:

```
myXHR[i].onload = (function(i) {
  return function() {
    if(myXHR[i].status == 200) {
      alert("Yay I worked");
      var data = myXHR[i].responseText;
    }
  }
})(i);
```

Because once I correctly save that `i` value in that function body this code will succeed for both calls.

I know this isn't the exact issue you're having, but I think it will be an issue regardless so you may as well give it a go right? It's not as though there have been a huge number of other answers unfortunately.

hope this helps..

Comment: Yea, unfortunately that didn't solve it but that does make sense thanks.